# margin: 0 auto; not doing as it should

Tags: css, html

Ok I have edited this question as the issue has changed slightly. Basically margin: 0 auto; is not working for me on 2 elements. They just will not centre in the middle of the page. I guess this jsfiddle shows a good example http://jsfiddle.net/Hr4uK/1/ Imagine the red box across the top is centred, every other div floats slightly to the right.

CSS:

```
#sliderFrame {margin: 0 auto; width:990px;} /*remove the "margin:0 auto;" if you want to    align the whole slider to the left side*/
.two-step {
width:990px;
background-color: #CADDC0;
margin: 0 auto;

border-bottom:5px solid #CADDC0;
} 
.var {
width: 990px;

}
.topimage {
margin: 0 auto;
width:990px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topimage">
<img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/test1.jpg" />
</div>


<div id="sliderFrame">
<div id="ribbon"></div>
<div id="slider">
    <a href="http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-1.jpg"  alt="Welcome to Menucool.com"  />
    </a>
    <img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" alt=""  />
    <img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-3.jpg"  alt="Pure Javascript. No jQuery.  No flash." />
    <img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-4.jpg" alt="#htmlcaption" />
    <img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-5.jpg"  width="968" />
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" style="display: none;">
    <em>HTML</em> caption. Link to <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>.
</div>
</div>


<div class="two-step">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/2-step-sfinder.png"  width="968" height="100"  class="show_hide" alt="3 steps" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Care to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with just the relevant bits included? I've no idea which "two divs" you're referring to, since there are a *lot* of divs in the code you've posted.

Comment: I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZLGM9/

Comment: Sorry, not got my heaed on today! I've updated the jsfiddle to show the problem but stripped out all the over complicated stuff and just used an image at the bottom (the light blue strip) as you can see it just doesn't go the correct width. The image itself is 990px

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain as the class of the image is 'show-hide' which has css of display none so isn't actually visible on the jsfiddle. The page with all of the info is here http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/newsliderdev.asp

Comment: Ok ignore previous messages, I definitely havent got my head screwed on! The updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/ZLGM9/2/ I removed the 'show-hide' class so you can now see the blue image at the bottom. The html states the image is 968 wide and the css for the slider states 968 wide but that isn't how it is showing. This is the best way I can describe it, hope this helps and someone can advise!

Comment: Thought I had an answer by adding around 600px of margin to the right but even though this works ok in safari, no good for IE, firefox or chrome. So still open to an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by hacking with the top menu as it was that that was slightly not centred.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set width on the img element.

Without doing this, the img will take up it's natural width. (That's why it was jutting out beforehand)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/B23XC/)**

```
#sliderFrame, .two-step, img
{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:968px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies fellas, I now have the sliderframe div and the image the same width however the issue is both ar enot centred correctly. if you look at the live page, they are both the same width but the top menu is centred and as you can see the sliderframe div and the image aren't centred on the page http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/newsliderdev.asp#.Udq1thYSyS1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want. So I assume you want the `div.two-step` be aligned with the other divs.

you have a class in your CSS .slidingDiv but it is not used in your HTML...

#sliderFrame {margin: 0 auto; width: 990px}

```
.two-step {
width: 968px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I also forced the width of the 990px wide image to be 968...
does what I think you want.
look at the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hr4uK/

Comment: The sliding div is used in the overall 'collapseable' block setup, basically when you click the blue image another box appears, click that then another appears etc (slidingDiv, slidingDiv1, slidingDiv2 etc.

Comment: then why is ist in the fiddle?

Comment: It was there in error to start with, it's not there now. Basically I'm sorted now other than I now have the sliderframe div and the image the same width however the issue is both ar enot centred correctly. if you look at the live page, they are both the same width but the top menu is centred and as you can see the sliderframe div and the image aren't centred on the page paycoservices.co.uk/newsliderdev.asp#.Udq1thYSyS1